# Why do I get a weird error about an uninstantiated template being undefined?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When I [compile this code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zh1GPYEef) with MSVC:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class> struct S { };
template<class T>
using Foo = std::integral_constant<unsigned, sizeof(S<std::underlying_type_t<T>>)>;
int main() { }
```

I get:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'S<_Underlying_type<_Ty,std::is_enum_v<_Ty>>::type>'
note: see declaration of 'S<_Underlying_type<_Ty,std::is_enum_v<_Ty>>::type>'
```

Why is this? If it's a bug, is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out a workaround (I think it's a longstanding bug):

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class> struct S { };

template<class T>
struct Bar : std::integral_constant<unsigned, sizeof(S<std::underlying_type_t<T>>)> { };

template<class T>
using Foo = typename Bar<T>::type;

int main() { }
```